# Click Element is not interactable - Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework, testcase

I was trying to click "CDE" from below code

```
<div class="accordion-toggle" role="button" aria-expanded="true"> 
    <!----> 
    <li _ngcontent-c1="" accordion-heading="" class="dropdown spaTest" >
         <a _ngcontent-c1="" class="btn-header" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <i _ngcontent-c1="" _ngcontent-c3="" class="fas fa-cog"></i> 
         ABC</a>
         &nbsp; 

         <a _ngcontent-c1="" class="btn-header" href="javascript:void(0)" >
            <i _ngcontent-c1="" _ngcontent-c3="" class="fas fa-users"></i>
         CDE</a>
         &nbsp; 

         <span _ngcontent-c1="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out" title="Logout"></span>
    </li> </div>
```

I have given,

```
Sleep   30
Page Should Contain Element  xpath=//a[contains(text(),'CDE')]

    --->  Working till this code
Click Element   xpath=//a[contains(text(),'CDE')]
```

When executing the click element, it is throwing element not interactable error.

I have increased the sleep time also, bot no luck.

Please help

Comment: Are you sure, that when you try to click the element the div is still expanded? (aria-expanded=true)

Comment: yes.. its expandable

Comment: What happens when you change `Page Should Contain Element ` with `Element Should Be Visible`?

Comment: Element should be visible is failing